# Drupal : i want to disaplay the information in content area when sub category is clicked

Tags: drupal

i had a title bar in ma site mean menu bar at the top, in which there are sub-categories.
presently when i click on any sub-category it show me the list of items on the left sidebar and also some items in the main content area.
now i want when i click any sub-category, it should show me the items (presently appearing in main content area) in side bar and in main content area discription of that item shall appeared.
can some1 kindly write steps how to do that :(

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views).